# Drupal 6 Clean URL and urls returning Not Found

Tags: php, drupal, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, clean-urls

My drupal site was working fine on local, when I uploaded it to testing server. It started causing problems 
First is its Clean URLs are now disabled . Can not enable it its saying
Your system configuration does not currently support this feature. The handbook page on Clean URLs has additional troubleshooting information.

Secondly few links are not working, like if I click on Administrator on top it gives me error page Not Found. 
`http://192.168.5.19/poa/admin` is not working , but if i add ?q manually it works. this is working . `http://192.168.5.19/poa/?q=admin`

I read a lot. tried rewrites but nothing worked.

Comment: Why no one is answering my question ?

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` enabled on your server? Have you tried looking in any `.htaccess` files to check all the rewrite rules contain the correct path?

Comment: @user1635914: Because it's unclearly written and difficult to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because my htaccess was not being read. To make it work edit conf/httpd.conf and set AllowOverride to All from none. Relaod using this in command line "service httpd reload". And all will start working. Now go to Clean URL option and enable it from Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

Fire this two query in your drupal database:

```
UPDATE variable SET value = 's:1:"0";' WHERE name = 'clean_url';    
DELETE FROM cache;
```

and  write

```
$conf['clean_url'] = 0;
```

in the settings.php end of the page.

This should work.